# How to change the frequency of x ticks for time data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I change the frequency of my x ticks to every hour using matplotlib.pyplot? I looked at similar posts, but could not figure out how to apply their solutions to my data since I only have times, not full dates. Here's an example of my data:

```
Time        SRH_1000m
14:03:00    318
14:08:00    321
14:13:00    261
14:17:00    312
14:22:00    285
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['14:03:00', '14:07:00', '14:08:00', '14:15:00'], 'value': [0,1,2,3]})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.plot(df['time'], df['value'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That worked great. Would you happen to know if I could get the ticks to start at 1400 and end at 2400 instead of starting at 14:04? It helps when comparing different data sets to have the ticks more consistent

Comment: Nevermind! I managed to figure out that comment question myself. I just changed the MinuteLocator part to ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0, 60]))